# React parou de de funciona "npm start" não faz nada

Tags: node.js, react, npm

### Estava desenvolvendo um projeto e quando fui da o "npm start" e simplesmente nada aconteceu e não sei como resolver pois não da erro nada simplesmente desliga [O que acontece](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOIxO.png)
No termina aparece simplesmente isso

> teste@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

---

Desinstalei o nodejs, apliquei o npm init, pensei que fosse o vs code e nada

Comment: rpz, pelo que eu vi na imagem que postou, está no diretório errado, não?

Comment: não, não está no diretório correto, é que crie de outro medo suspeitando que o problema está no "npx-create-app", mas pelo visto não